# Switching to a schema in a Spring Boot 2 + Redshift setup

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, amazon-redshift

I am able to connect to the Redshift cluster but I need to switch to a specific schema, otherwise the Hibernate executions all fail.

In PostgreSQL, you can switch to the schema by passing a `searchPath` URL argument but Redshift has that disabled.

I was thinking of running an SQL script that sets the `SEARCH_PATH` before Hibernate runs anything so the connection points to the proper schema.

Is there a proper way to do this from Redshift side?

Otherwise, how can I run an SQL script before Hibernate runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should specify the Schema in your beans, it should work, like below--

`@Table(name = "some_table", schema = "some_schema")`

Incase you are using Hibernate.cfg.xml, you could specify like,

```
...



<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="myschema"/>

...'
```

OR
if you are using native SQL queries

```
select c1, c2 from schema1.table1
```

Comment: schema is not being picked up for me